# Run single SQL build pipeline at a time

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

**TLDR**

I want to run only one instance of a build at a time that shares a resource that can only handle one execution at a time while still being able to run multiple agents at a time on other builds. Another option is to run an Azure SQL database instance within the build, if that is even possible.

1.) How can I restrict builds that share a resource to 1 agent at a time? I was looking for a named azure agent that can be limited or add some sort of namespace that can only be used one at a time.

2.) What would be a better approach to testing a SQL install script as part of a build pipeline.

**Details**

I have several build pipelines and release pipelines setup in Azure. One of my pipelines is testing a large SQL script for initializing new instances of a database. This is performed using the `Azure SQL Execute Query` task. Any errors encountered when running the SQL is supposed to kick back to Github as a failed build. However, when I increased the number of agents from 1 to 2 I encounter an issue every now and then where a build is triggered before the previous one finishes. This breaks the first build.

Here are the agents I am using

[image]

Comment: Your test process should be responsible for creating and tearing down any resources needed for the context of the test.

Comment: @DanielMann i would like it to be able to do so but I have not found a task that is capable of doing so with a SQL Server database. I considered making it spin up a new instance of Azure SQL to run the script but it may take considerable work to do so

Comment: Any error message when the first build breaks? For limiting one agent at a time. I think you can use agent demand as i posted below.

Comment: To get a clear view of creating the database in a fresh state, i drop everything to start with so the first drops, then creates everything but before it has completed the creation, the 2nd may start and drop things that breaks dependencies

Answer (score 0):

To limit one agent to builds, if i understand you correctly. You can try below steps.

First go to your build pipeline, Edit your pipeline. Specify the **demands** for your pipeline. Then the pipeline will only run on the agent that satisfy the demands.

For example, if i specify the demands like below pic. Then the pipeline will only run on the agent named agentname.

[image]

And you can find detailed capabilities of your agent and define custom capabilities. go **agent pools** under **Pipelines** in your **Project Settings** page.
Select your agent pool, select your agent and **Add a new capablity** to add custom capabilities. You can then use the custom defined capabilities as demands.
[image]

**Update:**

In yaml style pipeline, You can specify which agent to run your pipeline by define **vmImage**, Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pool) for details

```
pool:
  name: string  # name of the pool to run this job in
  demands: string | [ string ]  ## see below
  vmImage: string # name of the vm image you want to use
```

You can aslo try using **Azure Pipelines** agent pool, where you can point a specific agent to run your pipeline.

[image]

Hope you can find this helpful.

Comment: is it possible to create a named instance of the agent when using the Azure agent? or does this depend exclusive access to all azure agents?

Comment: Donot know if i understand you correctly? In yaml pipeline, you can define `vmImage` for the agent name to specify an agent to run your pipeline. Check above update. You can change your pipeline to yaml style if it satisfies you.

Comment: i was able to figure it out. instead of Agent.Name (it doesn't error but disappears) I added "sqlrunner" and then added exists. I need to verify that it doesn't run on the 2nd hosted agent to be sure

Comment: That's great, I think you can post your solution out, in case others may come across similar issue.